# Javascript Breaking on < & > in a GridView edit box

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, html-encode

I've got an Asp.Net GridView inside an UpdatePanel. It all works fine, except when one of the columns includes HTML special characters like `<` and `>`. The GridView is bound to a `List<Entity>` and the Entity class has a property `Regex` which is a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`.

At first I had this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RegEx">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="RegExLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Regex") %>' 
                   ToolTip='<%#Eval("Regex") %>' Width="102px" CssClass="Wrap" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RegExTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Regex") %>' 
                     Width="98px" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

With a value of `(?<capture>\d+)` this displayed `?\d+` when not editing, and when editing this row I got a script error and the edit, update and cancel buttons no longer work.

Then I tried the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512517/how-to-use-htmlencode-with-templatefields-data-binding-and-a-gridview) and had this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RegEx">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="RegExLabel" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Regex").ToString()) %>' 
                     ToolTip='<%#System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Regex").ToString()) %>'
                     Width="102px" CssClass="Wrap" />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="RegExTextBox" runat="server" 
                       Text='<%#System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Regex").ToString()) %>' 
                       Width="98px" />
     </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is slightly better, in that the tooltip and the non-editing version display correctly, but when I start editing I see: `(?&lt;capture&gt;\d+)` with the HTML Entities displayed raw. Does anyone know a way to encode the values (to stop the script error) while still displaying them correctly without the HTML entities in their raw state when editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RegEx">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal Mode="Encode" ID="RegExLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Regex") %>' 
                   ToolTip='<%#Eval("Regex") %>' Width="102px" CssClass="Wrap" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RegExTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Regex") %>' 
                     Width="98px" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and in the page directive add this `ValidateRequest="false"`